# Firebase createUser() does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm helping create a [site](http://www.mhsbyte.org/madness/index.html) which uses Firebase(which I have very little experience with), and everything works fine until this code:

```
  loginBase.createUser({
    email: school_email,
    password: password_result
  }, function(error, userData){
    if(error){
      switch(error.code){
        case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
          alert("Email has already been taken.");
          break;
        case "INVALID_EMAIL":
          alert("The email given isn't a valid address");
          break;
        default:
          alert("There has been in error updating an account");
      } 
    }else{
      alert("Successfully logged in.");
    }
  });
```

which doesn't create a user. 
I looked over the web, but I couldn't find an answer. 
Can anyone point out the problem or at least give me a place to start?
Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like email/password authentication is not enabled on your Firebase.

This becomes extremely obvious when you alert/log the error in your `default` case:

```
    default:
      alert("There has been in error updating an account: "+JSON.stringify(error));
      console.error(error);
```

You'll see:

```
{
  "code":"AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED",
  "details":"You can enable email / password authentication from the \"Login & Auth\" tab at https://loginbase.firebaseio.com."
}
```

So if you enable email / password authentication for your Firebase, you should be getting further.

You should still (get someone to) fix the other errors on the page though, because all of these sounds pretty lethal:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: loginbase is not defined
>
> FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (https://loginbase.firebaseio.com)